# vba function foreach range error #value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not a VBA developer but i need a function multile values return of a VLOOKUP.

I found this one:

```
Public Function CercaTableMultiplo(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, indexcol As Long)
    'updateby Extendoffice 20151118
    Dim x As Range
Dim result As String
result = ""

For Each x In lookuprange
    If x = lookupval Then
        result = result & " " & x.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
    End If
Next x
CercaTableMultiplo = result
End Function
```

i edit it as fallow

```
Public Function CercaTableMultiplo(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, indexcol As Long, delimitator)

Dim x As Range
Dim result As String
result = ""
Dim first As Boolean
first = True

For Each x In lookuprange
    If x = lookupval Then
        If first = True Then
        result = result & x.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
        first = False
        Else
        result = result & delimitator & x.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
        End If
    End If
Next x
CercaTableMultiplo = result
End Function
```

The parameters are (F217;Foglio2!E:G;3;", ")

It works when:

- the **first** column is little the **second** is *empty* and the **third** is populate.

Not works when:

- the **first** column is little the **second** is *populate* (like a description text) and the **third** is populate.

I suppose it is a overflow issue but my short VBA developer experience stops here,
there are some checking that can i do?

Comment: Columns in the sheet that you are referencing in the range parameter? #N/A implies that your first parameter is not found in the specified range.

Comment: Can you show examples of when it works and when it doesn't work? Maybe an image of the data? Are you calling this function via VBA?